# Yank all function declarations

Tags: vim, vi

Something I often have to do is make sure I have prototypes for all my functions in my C code at the top of file. What would be a way to quickly select all the function declarations in a .c file using vi/vim, so I can yank them and paste to the top of the file?

Note that I use one-line function declarations with the arguments inline, so every declaration will always be a single line.

Answer (score 3):

Start just above the first function and jump to the opening brace with `]M`. You can now jump to the next one with `]}]M` (`]}` = closing brace, then `]M` again), which is a bit long-winded, so map that to an f-key:

```
:nmap <F9> ]}]M
```

If you use "goldilocks" [style indenting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style), e.g.:

```
void foo (int bar) {
```

This takes you to the same line as the signature -- presuming it's all on one line.  If you use the slightly sillier but much more common K&R, Allman, or GNU styles, you're one line down, in which case you actually want:

```
:nmap <F9> ]}]Mk
```

`k` moves one line up. On the first function, yank the line into a named buffer, I'll use "p" for prototype, so `"pyy` (`yy` is for "yank line").  On the subsequent functions, you want to *append* to this buffer by capitalizing the name: `"Pyy`.

You could add that to the function key nmap if you are confident all the signatures are on one line.

```
:nmap <F9> ]}]Mk"Pyy
```

If not, you could map it to a separate key and use your brain appropriately when proceeding; you'll have to eyeball and manually paste multi-line sigs.

Once you've got all of them, you can paste that buffer with `"pp` -- the second p is for "paste buffer".  If you use goldilocks style, you now need to `:s/ {$/;/` those lines.